# Emacs add consistent indent rule to generic-x mode

Tags: emacs, major-mode

I wrote a very simple Emacs mode for Standard ML:

```
;; sml syntax
(require 'generic-x)

(define-generic-mode
    'sml-mode                          ;; name of the mode
  '(("(*" . "*)"))                           ;; comments delimiter
  '("fun" "fn" "let" "val" "datatype" "type" "case" "of" "end" "structure" "struct" "signature" "sig")
  '(("=" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("|" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    (">" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("<" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("-" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("+" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    (";" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("," . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("{" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("}" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("(" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    (")" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    (":" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("[" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)
    ("]" . 'font-lock-builtin-face))     ;; a built-in
  '("\\.sml$")                    ;; files that trigger this mode
  nil                              ;; any other functions to call
  "SML highlighting mode"     ;; doc string
  )
```

However, it will not indent consistently. I can't describe exactly how it indents, but it switches inconsistently between tabs and spaces and length of the spaces. The simplest rule I can think of is to always start a new line on the same column and tabbing always takes you to the next column that is a multiple of 4. Tabs should be spaces. How can I do this using the generic mode?

As a note on the mode definition, I am using the builtin-face incorrectly because the operator-face had no coloring. It does look ugly now though.

Comment: What have you tried so far in order to get the indentation behavior you'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: I strongly recommend you start with `define-derived-mode` rather than with `define-generic-mode` because the former will seamlessly grow to accomodate a fully-featured major mode whereas `define-generic-mode` will quickly impose limits that are inconvenient to work around.

E.g. you could rewrite your code as:

```
(defvar sml-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; Make (*...*) a comment.
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\( "()1" st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\) ")(4" st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\* ". 23n" st)
    st))

(defvar sml-font-lock-keywords
  `((,(concat "\\_<" 
              (regexp-opt '("fun" "fn" "let" "val" "datatype" "type" "case" "of" "end" "structure" "struct" "signature" "sig"))
              "\\_>")
     (0 font-lock-keyword-face))
    ("[][=|><-+;,{}():]" (0 font-lock-builtin-face))))

;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode sml-mode prog-mode "SML"
  "SML major mode."
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "(* ")
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) " *)")
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
       '(sml-font-lock-keywords)))

;;;###autoload
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sml\\'" . sml-mode))
```

W.r.t TABs and SPCs, "switching between them" is the default Emacs behavior (the attitude being that TAB is just an optimisation which we use when it's applicable).  If you don't like it, then put `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` in *your* `~/.emacs` and not in your major mode's definition since that is a personal choice unrelated to SML (which does not distinguish TABs and SPCs, contrary to, say, Haskell).

As for the indentation you suggest, you could start by adding `(set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) #'indent-relative)` which should make sure that by default indentation is just the same as the previous line; and for the "TAB should advance by 4 columns" maybe something like `(set (make-local-variable 'tab-stop-list '(4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64))` would do the trick (in more recent Emacsen, `'(4 8)` is sufficient because Emacs finally learned to "auto-extend the list".

But I'm curious: why not just use the existing `sml-mode` that's in GNU ELPA?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I will read it through again in more detail, but I just wanted to answer your last question. Both ocaml-mode (tuareg) and sml-mode have very strange indentation rules that I find frustrating enough to justify a different mode with simpler rules.

Comment: I suggest you try a parallel approach where you ask how to get sml-mode to indent your code the way you like it.

Comment: Given the information that you provided about indentation seemingly being something different from the particular mode I am using, a parallel approach would probably make sense. That said, I am also glad for the exposure to developing a mode.

Comment: BTW, another approach might be to start with something like: `(define-derived-mode my-sml-mode sml-mode "MySML" "My own SML mode." (set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) #'indent-relative))`.  IOW use the existing sml-mode but modify the parts you don't like.

Comment: Looking over your answer, I am confused about two parts. First, what does the syntax table do? Secondly, you define two variables (the syntax table and the font lock for keywords), but where do those get tied into the SML mode defined below? It just seems like you've defined two variables without associating them with anything. How do they get picked  up?

Comment: The syntax-table explains to Emacs how to recognize a comment (whereas comment-start/end explains to Emacs how to insert a new comment.  There's obviously redundancy here).  It's auto-used (based on its name) by define-derived-mode.  The sml-font-lock-keywords OTOH is not auto-used, I just had forgotten to add the corresponding setup in the sml-mode function (now fixed, thanks).

Comment: An issue with this method is that if I have a variable `eval`, the `val` section of it is highlighted. That is undesirable.

Comment: Indeed, you need `\\_<...\\_>` around the regexp.  I just added it.